# problem with metaplex.nfts().load()

Tags: metaplex-js

I have been trying to get `Nft` data instead of `Metadata` from a wallet key. I am using the `load` function as specified here: https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js#load

```
import {Metaplex} from "@metaplex-foundation/js";
const metaplex = new Metaplex(connection);
metaplex.nfts()
        .findAllByOwner({owner: walletKey.publicKey})
        .run()
        .then((nfts) => nfts.forEach(nft => console.log(metaplex.nfts().load(nft))));
```

However Typescript throws an error: `Argument of type 'Metadata' is not assignable to parameter of type 'LoadMetadataInput'. Property 'metadata' is missing in type 'Metadata' but required in type 'LoadMetadataInput'`.

Reading the docs show that `LoadMetadataInput` should take a type of `Metadata`. What did I do wrong?

@metaplex-foundation/js^0.15.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the shape of input `load` expects is `{metadata: Metadata}`. Where you're just passing in `Metadata` as you said.

Try this:

```
import {Metaplex} from "@metaplex-foundation/js";
const metaplex = new Metaplex(connection);
metaplex.nfts()
        .findAllByOwner({owner: walletKey.publicKey})
        .run()
        .then((nfts) => nfts.forEach(nft => console.log(metaplex.nfts().load({metadata: nft}))));
```

Although from that documentation it looks like you might also need to call `.run()` on the `load` result. So you might want something more like this (untested):

```
import {Metaplex} from "@metaplex-foundation/js";

const metaplex = new Metaplex(connection);

const nfts = await metaplex.nfts()
  .findAllByOwner({owner: walletKey.publicKey})
  .run()

nfts.forEach(nft => {
  metaplex.nfts()
    .load({metadata: nft})
    .run()
    .then(loaded => console.log(loaded))
})
```

Comment: Gee, thanks. I misread the struct as a type declaration. Silly mistake, thanks for pointing it out!